# Plotly расположение графиков в subplots

Tags: python, plotly

Кусок из скрипта, который строит графики в реальном времени:

```
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
          Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))  
def update_graph_live(n):
       df=pd.read_csv('/home/gluk/forstream.csv')
       ln=len(df)
       if ln<500:
            df1=df.tail(ln)
       else:
            df1=df.tail(500)
    
       fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, 
                shared_xaxes=True,
                vertical_spacing=0.03,
                horizontal_spacing = 0.02,
                column_widths=[0.65, 0.35])
fig['layout']['margin'] = {
    'l': 0, 'r': 0, 'b': 0, 't': 0
}
fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

fig.append_trace({
    'x': df1['T'], #Время
    'y': df1['HAE'],#Канал Восток
    'name': 'HAE',
    'mode': 'lines+markers',
    'type': 'scatter'
},1,1)
fig.append_trace({
    'x': df1['T'], #Время 
    'y': df1['HAN'], #Канал север
    'text': df1['T'],
    'name': 'HAN',
    'mode': 'lines+markers',
    'type': 'scatter'
},2,1)
fig.append_trace({ #График зависимости двух каналов
    'x': df1['HAE'],
    'y': df1['HAN'],
    'text': df1['T'], 
    'name': 'HAE vs HAN',
    'mode': 'markers',
    'type': 'scatter',
},2,2

)
fig.update_layout(height=700,
    template="plotly_white",
    margin=dict(
        t=10,
        b=0
        ))
return (fig)
```

Задача сделать так, чтобы последний график (позиция 2,2) имел квадратную форму и занимал часть или всю позицию (1,2). Квадратная форма необходима для того, чтобы сделать один масштаб осей конкретно на этом графике. Пока не нашел как сделать такую конфигурацию subplots в plotly. Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в методе `fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots` после `rows=2, cols=2,` явно указать спецификацию:
для сабплотов такого вида:

```
_______
   |
-------
_______
```

```
specs=[[{}, {}],
           [{"colspan": 2}, None]],
```

для

```
________
   |   
   |----
___|____
```

```
[[{'rowspan': 2}, {}], [None, {}]]
```

для

```
_______
   |
---|
___|___
```

```
[ [None, {}], [{'rowspan': 2}, {}]]
```

и т. д.

Comment: Увы. ValueError: No subplot specified at grid position (2, 2)

Comment: разберитесь со своими сабплотами или описанием вопроса. в позициях указывается ряд затем колонка.  по вашим данным, либо второй сабплот у вас должен быть 1,2 , а не 2,1. либо спецификация должны быть specs=[[{‘rowspan’: 2}, {}], [None, {}]] или [ [None, {}], [{‘rowspan’: 2}, {}]].

Comment: В вопросе все верно. Первый график позиция 1,1 первая строка,первый столбец. Второй график 2,1 вторая строка первая столбец. Третий график 2,2 вторая строка второй столбец. На вариант specs=[[{}, {}], [{"colspan": 2}, None]] ошибка No subplot specified at grid position (2, 2). На вариант specs=[ [None, {}], [{"rowspan": 2}, {}]] Exception: Some 'rowspan' value is too large for this subplot grid. На вариант specs=[[{"rowspan": 2}, {}], [None, {}]] ValueError: No subplot specified at grid position (2, 1)

Comment: @glukoff попробуйте для третьего графика указать не `,2,2` после `fig.append_trace({...})`, а `,1,2` и `specs=[ [None, {}], [{"rowspan": 2}, {}]]` соответственно в plotly.tools.make_subplots

Comment: Благодарю! Пришлось переставить столбцы местами, переписать specs и все заработало. В изначальном варианте работать не захотело. Почему так и не понял, хотя теперь все очевидно.  Есть другая проблема: необходимо сделать одинаковый масштаб по обоим осям только на последнем графике (График зависимости двух каналов). К сожалению, в документации нашел только как можно сделать одинаковый масштаб на всех графиках с помощью shared_xaxes и shared_yaxes. Но это вариант не подходит.

Comment: Вероятно вам нужно посмотреть документацию на https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.subplots.make_subplots.html по поводу параметра `row_heights`, если я правильно вас понял.